# Eclipse plugin development made easy

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I am about to work on an existing Eclipse plugin to enhance it a little. This is a new area for me and I would like to check if there is any Eclipse plugin which can make my life a little easy like showing previews for small changes at development time, help detect which code is representing what in UI etc instead of Run As or Debug As 'Eclipse Application'?

Comment: Nothing that I know of, it would be hard to do without running the plugin in the correct environment.

Comment: Any screen preview like we have for web development or VB environment where we can jump to code of component on screen or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is for future reference if someone looking for it. I found a tool called VisualEditor which is now retired/archived and this tool is replaced by WindowBuilder (built by Google) and its fantastic. [Try Here!](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)